# How to get previous months name's

Tags: sql-server

I have this query that returns data of previous months, as [Month -1].

```
Select [STORE] = ET_LIBELLE,

CASE WHEN YEAR(GP_DATEPIECE) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
AND  month(GP_DATEPIECE) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
THEN ISNULL([SALES], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [Month-1],

CASE WHEN YEAR(GP_DATEPIECE) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
AND  month(GP_DATEPIECE) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
THEN ISNULL([SALES], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [Month-2],

.
.
.

FROM PIECE
GROUP BY ET_LIBELLE
```

What i need, is to get Name of the PREVIOUS Months, inside [Months -1], ..

For ex : Current month is May :

```
------------------------------------------
Store -  April - March - February - January
------------------------------------------
S1    -  2620  - 8955 -  6541   - 7410
------------------------------------------
S2    -  3620  - 5455 -  6852   - 4810
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Use `DATENAME`. For example `DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())` will return `'May'` today (if you're using a English based language setting).

Comment: You can't have a dynamic column name without Dynamic SQL, @Hamza.soufiane . And we don't have enough of your query to provide that solution.

Comment: @hamza.soufiane Store entire query in an nvarchar variable, replace parts of month names with your formula like: '...as ' + dynamic calculation + 'rest of the query'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MM,-1, GETDATE()))
```

For generating dynamic column names, consider using dynamic SQL queries:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 1 AS '+DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MM,-1, GETDATE()))
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**Result**

[image]

```
In your case: 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select [STORE] = ET_LIBELLE,

CASE WHEN YEAR(GP_DATEPIECE) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
AND  month(GP_DATEPIECE) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
THEN ISNULL([SALES], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ' + DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MM,-1, GETDATE())) + ',

CASE WHEN YEAR(GP_DATEPIECE) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
AND  month(GP_DATEPIECE) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
THEN ISNULL([SALES], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ' + DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MM,-2, GETDATE())) + ',

.
.
.

FROM PIECE
GROUP BY ET_LIBELLE'
```

Comment: Thank's that's help me. Last question, as u see in my query i have to repeat all the previous 12 months, any solution ?

Comment: @hamza.soufiane You can try getting the list of all months in a temp table or outer to apply and join on a month number -1.